this bot can't be added to the attachment menu
I have created a Telegram bot and activated its program.
Now, according to Telegram's description, I have prepared a startapp for it, but it does not open on mobile, while it runs well on Windows Telegram and has no problems.
For example, check this address:
https://t.me/gamee?startapp=123456
enter image description here
When I click on the link in the mobile telegram, this text appears

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
